# Cocoapods Firebase pods update

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods, podspec

Good morning, i have a problem with updating my Firebase/Analytics and Firebase/Core pod.

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '5.1.0'
pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '5.3.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
end
```

if i run `pod install` i get the following output

```
Analyzing dependencies

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 5.15.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 5.15.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

with `pod outdated`:
[image: with <code>pod outdated</code>]

so i run `pod update`:
[image: so i run <code>pod update</code>]

But 'Firebase/Analytics' remains on version 5.1.0
Where am i wrong? i have already try to install repo master several times and also gem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the message says, you should do `pod repo update` first then do `pod update` after. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for you fast reply, this is the error i get with pod repo update 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyqlebaw3qxp566/pod_update.png?dl=0

Comment: @YvesHohler You may try remove Firebase/Analytics then replace Firebase/Core by pod 'FirebaseCore', '5.2.0'. It should work

Comment: Ok finnaly the project is compiling again, thak you so much, my podfile now looks like this:

'code' source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'FirebaseCore',  '5.2.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '5.16.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '5.16.0'
pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '5.5.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
end 'code'

Thank you so much!