# CocoaPods Firebase latest version can not update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, ios13

I was submitting my app to `Appstore` and `Appstore` send me that I have `ITMS-90809` issue. I use `Firebase` and `Firebase` use `UIWebView` in my app. **`Firebase` solved this problem after `Version 6.8.1` - September 10, 2019.** I want to update my pod but pod always install  `Firebase 5.20.2`.

How can I update `Firebase Version 6.8.1` or latest version?

My podfile :

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging' 
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

I tried  `pod update`. but not solved.
Also changed on my pod file
 like that

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging' '~> 6.8.1'
```

but this did not work.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

thanks.

[image: Firebase 5.20.2]
[image: UIWebView solved version]

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788691/cocoapods-firebase-pods-update

Comment: yeah tried but no work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy-paste from link to pod class files. I unlock for change to file and edit files.

Worked well. I hope App Store Team accept to my app

You can see updated Firebase from this Url:

https://github.com/mohamedsamirmohamedsalem/RealTimeChatApp/tree/master/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Utilities

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Don't add any version with Firebase Pod. Update your podfile with below pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging' 
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

I am sure that the issue will be resolved.
To check if the UIWebView is completely removed from the project or not, refer to below link:

[Replaced UIWebView with WKWebView, but still same error from Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575655/replaced-uiwebview-with-wkwebview-but-still-same-error-from-apple)

Comment: Please share the steps for how you are checking for UIWebView matches? Have you tried the link I shared? If yes, please share the screenshot

Comment: Akash Sharma I changed many days ago. if you say before , I was can do for screenshot . My app accepted. but thank you for want to help .